# Fixed point theorem for discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the below exercise from Pugh's analysis book.

> Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Prove that $f$ has at least one fixed point: an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = a$. Is the same true for discontinuous functions?

Here is my attempt.

> Notice that if $f(0) = 0$ or $f(1) = 1$, the theorem is proved. Suppose not. Define $g(x) = f(x) - x$, which is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Then since $f(0) \neq 0$, $g(0) \neq 0$, so $g(0) > 0$. Since $f(1) \neq 1$, $g(1) < 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $a \in [0,1]$ such that $g(a) = 0$. So $f(a) - a = 0$, so $f(a) = a$.

I am fairly sure that the result is not true for discontinuous functions, largely because I required continuity of $g$ to invoke the intermediate value theorem. I am having trouble finding a counterexample, however. Do I define a function piece-wise, with jumps at $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, to try to break the intermediate value theorem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You answered it yourself:  use a piecewise function.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexamples abound:  draw some pictures to find some.  For one, try
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in [0,1) \\ 0, & x =1. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in your proof. You defined g(x) = f(x) - x, and found an x-intercept of g. Graphically speaking, a fixed point of the function f is any point where the graph of f crosses the line y = x. So all you have to do is draw a graph that does not cross this line.